# Packaging Kivy application to Android - Windows

Tags: python, android, kivy, virtual-machine

I finished writing the code for a simple game using Kivy. I am having a problem converting it to Android APK, since I am using a windows computer. From some earlier research I got to know that using a Virtual machine is recommended, but I have no idea on how to download and use one :(, and if my slow PC can handle it... please help me. If possible, kindly recommend another  way to  convert to APK.

I am a beginner at coding as a whole, please excuse me if my question is stupid.

Answer (score 0):

you could just try downloading a virtual box and installing linux operating system or you could directly install it and keep it a drive called F or E and you could just install python on that and all the required pakages and start the build using buildozer as it is not available for windows. So try doing it. But I need to do it just now. Tell me after you have tried that cuz there are a lot of people online on youtube who would heloo you doing that work